# Перестановка  элементов в массиве Java не могу найти ошибку

Tags: массивы

Заранее спасибо
public class toUsd {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i, n;
    n = in.nextInt();
    int a[] = new int[n];
    int temp;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        a[i]  = in.nextInt();
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[n - i];
        a[n - i] = a[i];
    }
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
            System.out.println(a[i]);

    }
```

Comment: *
temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[n - i]; //  Exception in thread "main"           java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
 at class1.toUsd.main(toUsd.java:24)

        a[n - i] = temp;

Comment: i меняется от 0 до n-1. При i == 0 из a[n - i] получаем a[n] -- выход индекса за границы

Answer (score 1):

Строку `for(i = 0; i < n; i++){` стоит заменить на `for(i = 1; i < n; i++){`Тогда цикл не будет вылетать за границы массива.